# Redirect Loop Caused by changing Wordpress to a Multisite installation

Tags: wordpress, redirect

so I'm getting the 301 error (This webpage has a redirect loop...) trying to access the dashboard of a newly installed site within a newly installed multisite. I'm sure it's a server configuration error and not a cookies issue but I have no idea how to go about fixing it. Any suggestions?

It might help to say that the multisite installation was done *after* the initial site was built (the initial site will eventually become a sub site). If that helps at all...